# Visualizing interface implementations in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, visual-studio-2015, extension

Is there a way to visualize members of a class that are implementations of an interface in Visual Studio 2015. Specifically, in the C# code editor.

NetBeans has this feature natively, and displays a little marker icon in the left margin indicating that a class member implements/overrides a super-type member.

[image: An image of the NetBeans left margin with an icon indicating the member is an super-type implementation]

If it's not supported natively are there any *free*<sup>[1]</sup> extensions that would enable this?

---

1. Commercial extensions are of course valid answers too, but free is preferable (when isn't it?)

Comment: Visual studio has class diagrams for this, I don't know if it's a .Net only thing though. Might be worth a try ... but for netbeans, I would guess that you need some sort of add on.

Comment: @War Maybe misunderstanding: class diagrams are great, but when navigating through a code file, I'd like to see some visual indication of which members override/implement another member. If I define an interface in a NetBeans supported lang, and then implement it in a class, the implementing methods are tagged with that little icon in the class file. If I write another method in the class that exists independently of the interface, it won't be marked; allowing you to differentiate from implementation methods and just... class methods.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same functionality *in VS2015*. NetBeans already does it.